# Building a stacking constraint in Pyomo for Daily Fantasy Sports

Tags: python, pyomo, integer-programming

I am creating an integer program in Python using pyomo for Major League Baseball (MLB) daily fantasy. Given a lineup of 10 players (1 of each position plus 2 pitchers) and a salary cap, the program returns the lineup that maximizes projected points. I am trying to include an additional constraint - each lineup must have a 'stack' of at least 4, but no more than 5 players from one team. So, a feasible lineup could be:

| player | position | salary | team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| player1 | P | 5k | Reds |
| player2 | P | 5k | Orioles |
| player3 | 1B | 5k | Braves |
| player4 | 2B | 5k | Braves |
| player5 | 3B | 5k | Braves |
| player6 | SS | 5k | Braves |
| player7 | OF | 5k | Braves |
| player8 | OF | 5k | Red Sox |
| player9 | OF | 5k | Brewers |
| player10 | C | 5k | Giants |

I am focused on the team constraint. Here is example code for how I set up the salary constraint:

model.lineup is the binary decision variable = 1 if player is selected and = 0 if not selected

```
players = ...some list of players
salaries = ...some list of salaries
model = ConcreteModel()
model.lineup = Var(players, domain = Boolean)
salary_dict = dict(zip(players, salaries))
max_salary = 50000
model.salary_ct.add(sum(model.lineup[p] * salary_dict[p] for p in players) <= max_salary)
```

The issue with doing something like this for the team constraint is that it is not feasible to have lineups with exactly 'n' players from each team. How can I set up a constraint that forces at least 4 and no more than 5 (non-pitchers) from one team?

Comment: Is it the case that player-position and player-team combinations are each singular?  Meaning:  is each player only capable of playing 1 position and only rostered on 1 team?

Comment: well, some players have multiple position designations on DraftKings (they can be rostered as 2B OR 3B for example), but I solved for that already. But, yes 1 player can only be rostered once in the optimal lineup, and each player exists on only 1 team

Comment: I think a variant of this should work.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67648449/how-to-incorporate-or-condition-into-pulp-optimization-problem/67733644#67733644
I would probably index the “hire” decision by [player, position] if players can play multiple positions.

Comment: I indexed by [player, position category] where position category can be pitcher or non-pitcher. You can have up to 5 non-pitchers (batters) and 1 pitcher from one team.

Comment: OK.  Did the other post help with the teams reqt?  There are a couple options there…. Including indexing or sub-setting (because pairings are unique).  Or are you still stuck on that?

Comment: The other post helped, I just adjusted so it worked with pyomo, thank you!

Comment: @JRP do you happen to still have the pyomo conversion? I'm having trouble converting it and was looking for some help